# .htaccess, Rewriting language code to PHP vars

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried to find some examples here but none of them work for me.. I'm a newbie working with R.E.

I need some help on .htacess >  RewriteRule. How could I achieve this?

```
www.mysite.pt/folder/?a=home&id=22 -> www.mysite.pt/folder/index.php?lang=pt&a=home&id=22

www.mysite.pt/folder/en/?a=home&id=22 -> www.mysite.pt/folder/index.php?lang=en&a=home&id=22
```

**Notes:**

- both with and without "www"
- the ?a=home&id=22 is only an example, I would like to append the
  whole query-string.
- The 'folder' is needed until I release the website cause I have to
  test it on my client server (e.g. www.mysite.pt/site_v2/).

Thanks in advance for your help,

Pedro

Answer (score 0):

I can mainly help you out with regex. I did a few htaccess interventions in the past but don't know the details.

**www.mysite.pt/folder/?a=home&id=22 => www.mysite.pt/folder/index.php?lang=pt&a=home&id=22**

```
regex
(www\.)?mysite\.pt/folder/\?(.*)
replace with
www.mysite.pt/folder/index.php?lang=pt&$1
```

**www.mysite.pt/folder/en/?a=home&id=22 => www.mysite.pt/folder/index.php?lang=en&a=home&id=22**

```
regex
(www\.)?mysite\.pt/folder/en/\?(.*)
replace with
www.mysite.pt/folder/index.php?lang=en&$1
```

I recall that the order you specify the rewrite rules is important and AFAIK first one wins.

Why? It could be that multiple regexes match

This is not the case with these 2 regexes but something to be aware of

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to support only EN and PT?

I also expect that you have a lot of image, CSS, files, etc.  Will you want EN and PL versions of those as well?  Anyway, let's focus on the scripts for now.  Here you want to pick up URIs for `/somefolder/en/` and then  `/somefolder/`.  If you are using the DOCroot `.htaccess` then you'll need this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

RewriteRule   ^(.*?)/en/$   $1/en/index.php?lang=en  [L,NS,QSA]
RewriteRule   ^(.*?)/$      $1/pl/index.php?lang=pt  [L,NS,QSA]
```

Lookup the L,NS,QSA flags in the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).  You'll need the NS flag to stop subqueries biting you. The QSA flag merges the `lang` parameter with the rest of the query list.

If you want a fixed folder then replace the `(.*?)` and `$1` by the fixed folder name.  Also remember that your HTML references will need to work as well.  e.g. if a page includes an image `src="images/mygif.gif"` then this will either resolve to `<same directory as HTML file>/images/mygif.gif` from the browser perspective, e.g. `/folder/en/images/mygif.gif` so you'll need to figure out where to map these and add the corresponding rules.